# phpMyAdmin disable admin login

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, autologin

I have Ubuntu, and installed the phpMyAdmin package (currently 4:3.3.2-1). Every 30 minutes, it asks me to enter my username and password, for inactive session timeout. In earlier version of phpMyAdmin, setting a user/pass would entirely skip this login form and keep the session open indefinitely. This installation is on a dev machine (single user on closed private network) and I want to disable, or bypass that login form so I never have to actually input the user/pass again. I tried fiddling with the configuration files (there are like 3, not even sure which one is used) but nothing seems to change.

I've followed this thread : http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=743991 which brought me to this thread http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=499399 but there is no clear directive on how this be be solved.

Thanks!

Comment: Checkout my answer at following link:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/41158794/5558905

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Open `config.inc.php` on my debian instalation i can find it at `/usr/share/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`. Change `auth_type` and add in the first element on the array like this `$cfg['Servers'][1]` any data (like a host in `$cfg['Servers'][1]['host']`) need to auth.

**EDIT:**

Add this lines before first `for` statement in `config.inc.php`:

```
$cfg['Servers'][1]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][1]['host'] = 'localhost'; //edit if you have db in the other host
$cfg['Servers'][1]['connect_type'] = 'tcp';
$cfg['Servers'][1]['compress'] = false;
$cfg['Servers'][1]['extension'] = 'mysql';
$cfg['Servers'][1]['user'] = 'root'; //edit this line
$cfg['Servers'][1]['password'] = ''; // edit this line
```

Comment: right, I got the config.inc.php file ... but what next? I'm not sure I'm following you; how to disable/bypass the login form or phpMyAdmin with that solution?

Comment: Not all phpMyAdmin installations contain `config.inc.php`. Mine only contained `config.sample.inc.php`, but renaming that file and adding the lines above seemed to work.

Also, you may need to change the specified `root` password. Also, you can set `extension` to `mysqli` (more secure) if your server supports it.

Comment: You can simply drop the extension line, phpMyAdmin then uses mysqli per default if installed.

Comment: If you installed phpMyAdmin on Ubuntu through apt then your config will be located in `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`.

Answer (score 25):

On Ubuntu installation the config file is located at `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

Add/Correct these lines to the file:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = TRUE;
```

Comment: i notices that $cfg['Servers'][1]['auth_type'] = 'config'; is needed else this wont work

Comment: And if you do have a password, fill it in $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';  for this to work.

Answer (score 3):

Just need to edit /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php 
Open this file. 
find `/* Authentication type */`
add

```
/*costume config add by me */
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowRoot'] = TRUE;
```

here AllowNoPassword is responsible for allowing login without password

Answer (score 2):

In my case (Ubuntu 12.04, phpMyAdmin 4) I must edit same file `/etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php`

And I add:

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['host'] = 'localhost';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'MyPassword';
```

AFTER

```
/* Authentication type */
```

comment (about line 107)

Comment: Thank you for the update. This question has been quite popular :)

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to kachar and matthy's answer if you have have `phpmyadmin/config.sample.inc.php` instead of `phpmyadmin/config.inc.php` please rename the sample file. It solves in my case and detected as config file.