# Auto-login phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mysql, cookies, authentication, phpmyadmin

We want to auto login users in phpMyAdmin. Now we have a web-interface, written in PHP. Users can login. After logging in, they can click on the `SQL` link in the menu that opens phpMyAdmin. Is there a way to log them in automatically? Is it possible to set cookies for phpMyAdmin or something to let them use it? 
We don't want to turn off phpMyAdmin's login; each user has his own MySQL user/pass combination. So we need to pass the username/password settings to phpMyAdmin.

Comment: Many web hosting providers do this, but I think they build custom authentication to check against their back-end login. Not sure whether anything exists out of the box for this (it might, though)

Comment: I imagine that since PHPMyAdmin is open source, these sites are simply changing the code to accept a POST from their own site.  But that's a guess.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can simply post the username in a field named `pma_username` and the password in `pma_password`. Or, if you're using http auth mode you can create a link with username and password like `http://user:pass@www.host.com/phpmyadmin/...`

Comment: See [this discussion](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4174317/what-is-crossdomain-xml-file/4174355?noredirect=1#comment16322199_4174355) on the same matter :)

Comment: Since there is a configuration that exists in phpMyAdmin, you should not resort to a `hacky` solution. The answers following this answer give a much better solution. Regards,

Answer (score 91):

Add code in config.inc.php below of /* Authentication type */. It exists in the root folder

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = '';
```

Comment: the first line where you change 'cookie' to 'config' is what causes PMA to remember the password. Otherwise, you will have to enter the PW each time!

Answer (score 41):

**Edit config.inc.php**

Location : /etc/phpmyadmin/config.inc.php

Find for the blow code

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
```

And replace the line of code by blow code

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'root';
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'your_password';
```

If your password null or '' the uncomment the blow line

```
//$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

to

```
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['AllowNoPassword'] = TRUE;
```

then it will work fine !

Comment: It's `user` not `username` . Ref: https://docs.phpmyadmin.net/en/latest/config.html#cfg_Servers_user

Comment: Bad! Bad and bad! Sucurity reasons!

Answer (score 14):

config.inc.php

```
/* Authentication type */

//$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == '::1' (**ipv6**)
//$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == '127.0.0.1' (**ipv4**)

if ($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] == '::1') {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'config';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['user'] = 'user';
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['password'] = 'password';
} else {
    $cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type'] = 'cookie';
}
```

Comment: Please do not edit this post. This definition works just fine. Thx

Answer (score 5):

Sometimes when working at your local environment it annoys to login each time.
To avoid it you can do the following:

Add following lines at bottom of file:

> phpmyadmin\config.inc.php

```
$cfg['LoginCookieValidity'] = 10000; // Keep long validity :)-
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['user']          = 'root'; // Your user name
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['password']      = 'root'; // Your password
$cfg['Servers'][$i]['auth_type']     = 'config';
```

After that shutdown your db server & restart again.
Now check & you will see that you will login without entering user name & password.

Answer (score 3):

Things are much easier in 2020 if you need this for development. Just set environment variables:

```
PMA_USER: "the-root"
PMA_PASSWORD: "the-password"
```